# Mostrar objeto en Angular que cuenta el número de palabras repetidas

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy intenando mostrar un Object wordCounts, este objeto almacena una serie de palabras con un valor que es el número de veces que una palabra se repite en una cadena, me gustaría poder mostrar esta variable en orden por el número de repeticiones que una palabra tiene, y solo quiero que se muestren las 20 palabras repetidas. El principal problema que tengo es que, es que el código me devuelve un JSON que no tengo forma de poder meter cada palabra dentro de un div para poder darle un estilo.

**project-details.ts**

```
getWordCount(str) {
  let arrayOfWords = str.split(/\s+/);

  var wordCounts = Object.create(null);

  for(let i = 0; i<arrayOfWords.length; i++){
    let word = arrayOfWords[i];

    if(!wordCounts[word]){
      wordCounts[word] = 1;
    }else{
      wordCounts[word] ++;
    }
  }
    return wordCounts;  
  };
```

**project-details.html**

```
 <p>{{getWordCount(str) | keyvalue | json}}</p>
```

**lo que me muestra**

```
[ { "key": "También", "value": 1 }, { "key": "Un", "value": 1 }, { "key": "algoritmo", "value": 1 }, { "key": "aunque", "value": 1 }, { "key": "caracteres", "value": 1 }, { "key": "cifrado", "value": 1 }, { "key": "codificados", "value": 1 }, { "key": "composición", "value": 2 }, { "key": "cualquier", "value": 1 }, { "key": "de", "value": 5 }, { "key": "descifrado", "value": 1 }, { "key": "destinatario", "value": 1 }, { "key": "en", "value": 1 }, { "key": "es", "value": 2 }, { "key": "escritura", "value": 1 }, { "key": "forma", "value": 1 }, { "key": "generados", "value": 1 }, { "key": "imprimibles", "value": 1 }, { "key": "no", "value": 1 }, { "key": "original.", "value": 1 }, { "key": "para", "value": 1 }, { "key": "persona,", "value": 1 }, { "key": "por", "value": 2 }, { "key": "puede", "value": 1 }, { "key": "que", "value": 1 }, { "key": "que,", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sentido", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sentido.", "value": 1 }, { "key": "ser", "value": 1 }, { "key": "signos", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sistema", "value": 1 }, { "key": "su", "value": 1 }, { "key": "sí", "value": 1 }, { "key": "texto", "value": 1 }, { "key": "tienen", "value": 1 }, { "key": "un", "value": 2 }, { "key": "una", "value": 3 }, { "key": "unidad", "value": 1 } ]
```

Lógicamente con este resultado no puedo añadirle ningún tipo de estilo.

Comment: no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres mostrar. Pero si te llega el json (lo puedes serializar a objeto javascript con JSON.parse(json))  y puedes usar `ngFor` para mostrar la lista de palabras.

Answer (score 0):

En otro foro me contestaron a mi pregunta y lo cierto es que funcionó, así que dejo la solución que me ofrecieron:

**Controller**

```
export class WordComponent {
  wordCount: any;

  getWordCount(str) {
  let arrayOfWords = str.split(/\s+/);
  let wordCounts = Object.create(null);

  for(let i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.length - 1; i++){
    let word = arrayOfWords[i];
    wordCounts[word] ? wordCounts[word]++ : wordCounts[word] = 1;
  }

  return wordCounts;  
};

}
```

**Template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="wordCount">
  <p class="style" *ngFor="let word of wordCount | keyvalue">{{ word.key }} : {{ word.value }}</p>
</ng-container>
```